# URL to PHP with parameter to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

We have been stuck on a problem we can't seem to fix even with all the articles on StackOverflow; We have a website like "www.example.nl/domain.php?user=somename" and we need our users to reach that page by entering "somename.example.nl". We have been trying for ages, and none of the answers we find work for us.

We have tried code similar to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ domain.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).example.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.nl$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ domain.php?user=%2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Also, before that we tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.nl$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ domain.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

If this is a repost, I apologize, but I have been stuck on this for hours and I really need an answer for a project that's due tomorrow.

Thank you for taking the time to help us!

Comment: You do have the DNS setup correctly, yes?

Comment: We have not changed the DNS, seeing as we don't want the actual subdomain, we just want users that enter the URL as a subdomain see the page at "www.example.nl/domain.php?user=somename".

Comment: Yes but the user's computer still has to know how to lookup somename.example.nl and resolve that to an IP address, where it can send the HTTP request.

Comment: That's what we're trying to achieve with htaccess files. We shouldn't have to make changes to our DNS because we're not manually creating subdomains for our users.

Comment: Yeah, you do.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to not only set up the code and web server to handle this, but also the DNS configuration.  You need to use a wildcard match to redirect all subdomains to the same IP address.

This is how opening a URL in a web browser works:

1. The web browser must first do a DNS lookup to translate the hostname (in your example, `somename.example.nl` into an IP address
2. The web browser sends a HTTP request to the IP address it finds with the request URL containing the FQDN that was entered (`somename.example.nl`)
3. The web server uses virtual host or some other configuration type to determine how to handle a request for the given FQDN.

This name `somename.example.nl` therefore has to be resolvable through DNS, otherwise the user's computer won't know where (to which IP address) to send the HTTP request.

Comment: Basic info on wildcard DNS entries, I'm sure you can find better articles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record